# Sessions in Yii

Tags: php, session, yii

Here I go what am doing is I am using

```
 Yii::app()->SESSION['userid']
```

with no

```
  Yii::app()->session->open();
```

at login

```
  Yii::app()->session->destroy();
```

at logout

I wanna know if dont do the open and destroy session is it worthy . Does Yii do it internally.

One more strange thing I dont know whats happening. In the same browser for a session I can login for multiple users .. this should not happen so.Is it that i am not using the open and destroy session methods .

```
 public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    Yii::app()->session->clear();
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->module->returnLogoutUrl);
}
```

Please let me know how do i figure this out

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For creating yii session

```
Yii::app()->session['userid'] = "value";
```

You can get value like this

```
$sleep = Yii::app()->session['userid'];
```

And unset session like

```
unset(Yii::app()->session['userid']); # Remove the session
```

In case of user signs out , you have to remove all the session.

```
Yii::app()->session->clear();
```

After this, you need to remove actual data from server

```
Yii::app()->session->destroy();
```

Comment: unset()  ,destroy() ,clear() session should it be used in logout

Comment: if you use yii auth, you need to call logout() method https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L258

Comment: Yii::app()->session->clear(); in action logout ........ In the same browser for a session I can login for multiple users .. this should not happen so.Is it that i am not using the open and destroy session methods ..... this is i wanna figoure out

Comment: try Yii::app()->user->logout(true);

Comment: What if i have one common server i.e localhost , and there is two directory like test1 and test2 and both of this having two yii frameworks installed and working in a separate way. In this case if you will change the value of Yii::app()->session['user_id'] then it will affect to both in case of same session variable. Have you any solution with this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't clear session, only logout:

```
Yii::app()->user->logout(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you craeted session it will allow you in same browser multiple time, i mean for same url it will allow you to login, you can just do it rename your session variable with different name and check that particuller variable to login with that.

Session is a Web application component that can be accessed via Yii::$app->session.

To start the session, call open(); To complete and send out session data, call close(); To destroy the session, call destroy().

Session can be used like an array to set and get session data. For example,

```
$session = new Session;

$session->open();

$value1 = $session['name1'];  // get session variable 'name1'

$value2 = $session['name2'];  // get session variable 'name2'

foreach ($session as $name => $value) // traverse all session variables

$session['name3'] = $value3;  // set session variable 'name3'
```

Answer (score 0):

In YII, the session is handled by 'CHttpSession' class - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession

Should you use the method 'open()' `Yii::app()->session->open();` depends on your configuration. If in the `main.php`, you have set the 
 
`'session' => array (
    'autoStart' => true,
),` then the Session will be started automatically by YII itself.
You can refer the source code for the method 'init()' here - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/CHttpSession.php#L83

Regarding your question about using the methods 'close()' or 'destroy()', the method 'close()' only unsets the keys of Session but 'destroy' removes the whole session data