# Session in Yii application

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to learn `sessions in Yii`, thus I created a simple login form. Also I want to "set" session in this project.

My **login action**

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    Yii::app()->session['userid'] = "value"; // where i should put line ??

    $model=new LoginForm('login');
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='form-reg')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['regist']))
    {
        $model->username=$_POST['istiad'];
        $model->password=$_POST['parol'];

        if($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
            $this->redirect(array( 'update','id'=>$this->getIdByUsername($model->username ) ));
            /*  $this->render(
                  'update',array(
                      'model'=> $this->loadModelByUsername($model->username ) ) );*/
        }
    }
    else
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
}
```

**logout action**

```
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    unset(Yii::app()->session['userid']);   // also this,
    Yii::app()->session->clear();           // this
    Yii::app()->session->destroy();         // and this line ?? 

    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
}
```

p.s: PLEASE EXPLAIN ME what is the `userid` in `unset(Yii::app()->session['userid']);` ? I couldn't understand (because I'm new in Yii). It's just only a variable or any *attribute* of the db table name?

I copied the lines from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965023/sessions-in-yii).

Thanks. Best regards.

Comment: `userid` session variable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set session after validation user name and password. Like here..

```
if($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
        Yii::app()->session['userid'] = "value"; //here
        $this->redirect(array( 'update','id'=>$this->getIdByUsername($model->username ) ));
}
```

---

unset destroys the specified variable.

```
unset(Yii::app()->session['userid']);
```

Here `userid` is `session` variable. It is destroyed.

---

```
Yii::app()->session->clear();
```

`clear()` is used to remove all sessions. 
After `clear()`, you need to remove actual data from server using

```
Yii::app()->session->destroy();
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I'll try your codes...   but I couldn't understand this point: can i change 'userid'  with any another variable (exp: mirjalal)  or it's name of the column in db table ?? i keep the user's id in 'idperson' column.  So should i change it?  FINALLY; should I need add some lines in **protected/config/main.php**  ?  because I really don't know what I must do about the session. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can change `userid` to `mirjalal` and it is not a column of database table. For more about session: http://www.refulz.com/configuring-session-in-yii-framework-chttpsession/