# Checking logged in or not

Tags: php, session, authentication, yii2

I am trying to check if the user is logged in or not using session variable. but not being able to. I am using default login of yii framework. This is the controller action:

```
public function actionLogin()
{

  if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index');  
  }

  $model = new LoginForm();
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()){   
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = TRUE;

    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index');      
  }

  return $this->render('login', [
    'model' => $model,
  ]);

}
```

and for checking if the user is logged in or not i used:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
  $session = Yii::$app->session;
  if (isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {   
    echo "yes!";
  }
  else {
    echo "no!";
  }
}
```

It displays no! even if i am logged in.What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965023/sessions-in-yii

check this link

Comment: Why do you want to use session for checking the user is logged in or not. isGuest() method exactly does that.

Comment: because i also need to get the user id of the logged in user.@Chinmay

Comment: You can get the logged in user id with Yii::$app->user->getId() in advanced template. Or if the user is logged in you can print the session variable throuhh print_r(Yii::$app->user->identity)

Comment: oh. ok thanks. i just need it found it `Yii::$app->user->id;`

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 advanced app comes by default with a working example of the login,if you used by default login system then you have complete object of loged in user:

```
 print_r(Yii::$app->user);
```

You can access `Yii::$app->user->id, Yii::$app->user->name`

If you want session then you can do that also.

```
use  yii\web\Session;
$session = Yii::$app->session;
// check if a session is already open
if ($session->isActive) ...
// open a session
$session->open();
// close a session
$session->close();
// destroys all data registered to a session.
$session->destroy();
```

[Reference](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/session-handling-in-yii-framework-2-0/)