# Get the ID from the session public function search () in Yii1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addCondition('id=1');

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('login',$this->login,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('random_pass',$this->random_pass,true);
    $criteria->compare('default_number_of_devices',$this->default_number_of_devices);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
         'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'name ASC',)


    ));
}
```

I use ID `1` like  `$criteria->addCondition('id=1')`, it's not automatic just display record with `id=1`, how can I get automatic ID from user season login.

Comment: Possible duplicates of :-  [Sessions in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20965120/4248328)

Comment: i use try     $criteria->addCondition('Yii::app()->user->id');  but it error

Comment: check session data first and then change code accordingly.

Comment: in view if i write Yii::app()->user->id is get automatic id, how put it in model

Comment: if you want to pass it to modal function then get the id on controller side first and then pass it as a parameter to the modal function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $sas= Yii::app()->user->id;
    $criteria->addCondition("id=$sas");
    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('login',$this->login,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('random_pass',$this->random_pass,true);
    $criteria->compare('default_number_of_devices',$this->default_number_of_devices);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
         'sort'=>array('defaultOrder'=>'name ASC',)


    ));
}
```

desc id like this $sas= Yii::app()->user->id; i think it run

Answer (score 0):

Your `search()` method already has code for filtering by user ID:

```
$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
```

All you need to do is to set `id` property of model to ID of current. So your controller action should look like this:

```
$model = new MyModel('search');
if (isset($_POST['MyModel'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['MyModel'];
}
if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
}
$model->id = Yii::app()->user->id;

$dataProvider = $model->search();
```

---

You should not use `Yii::app()->user` directly in your model - it breaks MVC pattern and you will not be able to use this method in console for example. Global state should be handled and passed to model at controller level.